# How to programmatically handle a user before committing to database in Flask-User?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

Simply put I'm creating a `User` in Flask-User but I want to programmatically determine certain fields when the `User` is created. Namely I want to assign the `User` a UUID4.

I've started with the following template: [Flask-User-starter-app](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app)

I've defined the field I need in my `models.py`:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
__tablename__ = 'users'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

...

public_uuid = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False, unique=True)

...
```

However I seem to be unable to find a place where I can intercept the user object and set `user.public_uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex`

I've tried declaring it in my form (though I figured beforehand that wouldn't work): `class MyRegisterForm(RegisterForm): public_uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex`

So I end up with an error that public_uuid is `Null` when writing to the database.

Where can I handle my user object before it's committed to the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `default` parameter of `public_uuid` column to a function.

```
def generate_uuid():

    return uuid.uuid4().hex

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    # ...

    public_uuid = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False, unique=True, default=generate_uuid)
```

Comment: It all seems so obvious now. I had played around with `default` but was passing it `uuid.uuid4().hex` directly which lead to a single uuid being created at instantiation. But this way makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A decent solution which depends on `public_uuid` being nullable is to add the following to your `__init__.py` or `init_app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)           # The WSGI compliant web application object
...
@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def assign_public_uuid(sender, user, **extra):
    user.public_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
    db.session.commit()
```

This registers `assign_public_uuid()` with the Flask-User signal `user_registered` and depends on the `blinker` package being installed. Since `user_registered` isn't fired until the user confirms their registration via email, and there's no intermediate signal (like `user_created`) we'll need to leave `public_uuid` Nullable.

I'd also be very appreciative is someone has an approach that creates the UUID at signup (before email confirmation) so that the UUID can have a not-Nullable constraint.

More info on handling Flask-User's signals here: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/signals.html